# How do i properly add characters to string in recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

So i have this function  EDIT:Whole program as requested

```
//This is a java program to construct Expression Tree using Infix Expression
import java.io.*;
public class Infix_Expression_Tree
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        
        String result="";
       
        File vhod = new File(args[0]);
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vhod));
        
            Tree t1 = new Tree();
            
            String a = reader.readLine();
            t1.insert(a);
            t1.traverse(1,result);
            System.out.println("rez "+ result);
           
            ch = reader.readLine();
    
    }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 
class Node
{
    public char data;
    public Node leftChild;
    public Node rightChild;
 
    public Node(char x)
    {
        data = x;
    }
 
    public void displayNode()
    {
        System.out.print(data);
    }
}
 
class Stack1
{
    private Node[] a;
    private int    top, m;
 
    public Stack1(int max)
    {
        m = max;
        a = new Node[m];
        top = -1;
    }
 
    public void push(Node key)
    {
        a[++top] = key;
    }
 
    public Node pop()
    {
        return (a[top--]);
    }
 
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (top == -1);
    }
}
 
class Stack2
{
    private char[] a;
    private int    top, m;
 
    public Stack2(int max)
    {
        m = max;
        a = new char[m];
        top = -1;
    }
 
    public void push(char key)
    {
        a[++top] = key;
    }
 
    public char pop()
    {
        return (a[top--]);
    }
 
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (top == -1);
    }
}
 
class Conversion
{
    private Stack2 s;
    private String input;
    private String output = "";
 
    public Conversion(String str)
    {
        input = str;
        s = new Stack2(str.length());
    }
 
    public String inToPost()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '+':
                    gotOperator(ch, 2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    gotOperator(ch,1);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    gotOperator(ch, 3);
                    break;
                case '(':
                    s.push(ch);
                    break;
                case ')':
                    gotParenthesis();
                    //s.pop();
                    break;
                default:
                    //gotOperator(ch, 0);
                //break;
                   output = output + ch;
            }
        }
        while (!s.isEmpty())
            output = output + s.pop();

        //System.out.println("to je output iz inToPost " +output);
        return output;
    }
 
    private void gotOperator(char opThis, int prec1)
    {
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            char opTop = s.pop();
            if (opTop == '(')
            {
                s.push(opTop);
                break;
            } else
            {
                int prec2;
                if (opTop == '+')
                    prec2 = 2;
                else if(opTop=='*')
                    prec2=1;
                else
                    prec2 = 3;
                if (prec2 <= prec1)
                {
                    s.push(opTop);
                    break;
                } else
                    output = output + opTop;
            }
        }
        s.push(opThis);
    }
 
    private void gotParenthesis()
    {
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            char ch = s.pop();
            if (ch == '(')
                break;
            else
                output = output + ch;
        }
    }
}
 
class Tree
{
    private Node root;
 
    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }
 
    public void insert(String s)
    {
        Conversion c = new Conversion(s);
        s = c.inToPost();
        
        Stack1 stk = new Stack1(s.length());
        s = s + "#";
        int i = 0;
        char symbol = s.charAt(i);
        Node newNode;
        while (symbol != '#')
        {
            if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9' || symbol >= 'A'
                    && symbol <= 'Z' || symbol >= 'a' && symbol <= 'z')
            {
                newNode = new Node(symbol);
                stk.push(newNode);
            } else if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '/'
                    || symbol == '*')
            {
                Node ptr1=null;
                Node ptr2=null;
                //if(!stk.isEmpty()){
                ptr1 = stk.pop();
                if(!stk.isEmpty()){
                ptr2 = stk.pop();
                }
                //}
                newNode = new Node(symbol);
                newNode.leftChild = ptr2;
                newNode.rightChild = ptr1;
                stk.push(newNode);
            }
            /*else if(symbol=='/'){
                Node ptr = stk.pop();
                newNode = new Node(symbol);
                newNode.leftChild = ptr;
                newNode.rightChild=null;
                stk.push(newNode);

            }*/
            symbol = s.charAt(++i);
        }
        root = stk.pop();
    }
 
    public void traverse(int type,String result)
    {
        
                System.out.println("Preorder Traversal:-    ");
                preOrder(root,result);
             
    }
 
    private void preOrder(Node localRoot, String result)
    {   
        if(root==null){
            return;
        }
        
        if (localRoot != null)
        {
            if(localRoot.data == '/'){
            preOrder(localRoot.leftChild,result);
            result=result + localRoot.data;
            //StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            //stringBuilder1.append(result).append(localRoot.data);
            System.out.println(result);
            //localRoot.displayNode();
            preOrder(localRoot.rightChild,result);
            return;

           
        }else{
             //System.out.println("trenutni root je" );
             //localRoot.displayNode();
             result=result + localRoot.data;
            // StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            //stringBuilder1.append(result).append(localRoot.data);
            System.out.println(result);
             preOrder(localRoot.leftChild,result);
             //result=result + localRoot.data;
             //System.out.print(root.data);
             preOrder(localRoot.rightChild,result);
            
            //System.out.print(root.data);
            //preOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
            return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my problem with it is that with localRoot.DisplayNode() i get the result i want. But when i add the same thing to the String result it adds data, until i get to leaf of the tree(leaf doesnt have left/right child) so it returns to previous recursive call, and goes to right child, here somewhere  the leaf(from which we came back) isnt in String anymore. How do i fix this?

String is defined in main method

Comment: Can you please post the code of the whole class? We cannot see the definition for `root`, and `result`. It would also be helpful to see how `Node.leftChild` and `Node.rightChild` are defined. Please post also your main method with the call to `preOrder()`.

Comment: Also, please describe exactly what is `preOrder()` supposed to do. Give an example of input data and what do you expect the method to accomplish.

Comment: I updated the post, i added a whole program so you can see where stuff comes from

Comment: Just a side note, what is your main goal? Do you want to parse expressions? If so, I would recommend using a parser library. I personally use ANTLR4, which is awesome, but there are others out there. A simple expression grammar can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mattmcd/5277890). By using ANTLR4 you can save a lot of writing and debugging effort indeed.

Comment: Please post also the input data file.